# Link Expander action to RowDefinition height

Tags: wpf, expander, grid-layout

I have the following grid:

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...

                <Expander Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <TextBox />
                </Expander>
```

The text box fills the expander. I would like to set this up such that when the bottom row is expanded, the row heights are Auto / * / *, and when the bottom is collapsed, the row heights are Auto / * / Auto. I've tried (without success) at using style triggers to do this, and would like to do this in XAML instead of code as much as possible. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I just had this exact problem last night, haven't figured a good solution tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far this is my ugly workaround:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Expander">
        <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="ExpanderGrow"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Collapsed" Handler="ExpanderGrow"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

...and the CS required:

```
    public void ExpanderGrow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Expander expander = (Expander)sender;
        Grid grid = (Grid)expander.Parent;
        int index = Grid.GetRow(expander);
        RowDefinition rowdef = grid.RowDefinitions[index];

        rowdef.Height = new GridLength(1,
            expander.IsExpanded ? GridUnitType.Star : GridUnitType.Auto);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two easy ways of doing this

The first would be to adjust the Grid's `RowDefinitions` based on the `Expander.IsExpanded` value. I have some [GridHelpers on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) that allows you to bind the Grid's rows and column definitions instead of having to manually define them, which makes this much easier. Using those helpers, the end result would look like this:

```
<Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="3">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="local:GridHelpers.StarRows" Value="1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyExpander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="local:GridHelpers.StarRows" Value="1,2" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>

    ...

    <Expander x:Name="MyExpander" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox />
    </Expander>

</Grid>
```

The second option would be to use a `Converter` and `Trigger` that sets the `Expander.MinHeight` to `(Grid.ActualHeight - Row0Content.ActualHeight) / 2` when it's expanded. I also have a [MathConverter on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) that may make this easier, or you can just create your own.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Height="50" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />

    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Expander.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander }">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding 
                            ElementName=MyGrid, 
                            Path=ActualHeight,
                            Converter={StaticResource MathConverter},
                            ConverterParameter=((@VALUE-50)/2)" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>

        <TextBox />
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

This converter on my blog will only work if you know the height of Row0 ahead of time since its a regular `IValueConverter`, however it's pretty easy to convert to an `IMultiValueConverter` if you need to pass it Row0's height as well. I actually have the code for that already, but I haven't gotten around to updating my blog post yet.

Comment: These seem good, but... the first requires an extra dependency, and the second one defeats the mechanism of row definition units by doing the average manually. Correct me if I'm wrong - the second one would need to be modified whenever you add a new row to the grid.

Comment: @Reinderien You are correct that the 2nd implementation would need to be adjusted anytime you adjust the `Grid`, however you could easily do the same thing with an `IMultiValueConverter` and pass it whatever parameters you need so it wouldn't matter what the rest of the Grid looks lik. The 1st one is just an `AttachedProperty` that modifies the `RowDefinitions` whenever the triggered value change, very similar to your own answer (which is also a valid way of doing it).